# Sol contract analysis

Tags: spl-token, token, token-2022, smart-contract, contract

Hey I come from ethereum. Im conducting contract audits for adding new tokens to our platform. I can't seem to find the source code for a lot of these SPLs and token2022. like on ethscan the contract is typically uploaded to ethscan. Does anyone know how to do this in solana?

Answer (score 3):

You can locate those programs within:

- https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library

For the SPL token:

- https://spl.solana.com/token
- https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/program

And for the token2022:

- https://spl.solana.com/token-2022
- https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/program-2022

Comment: How can i check for added functionality outside of the programs inheritance?

Comment: On solana extra functionality will be added via token extension to token2022 program. https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions